# C++ / RS232C Serial-Port / Asynchronous read buffer by event callback / don't use thread

Tags: c++, asynchronous, mfc, serial-port

how can i receive RS232C data by callback func?

i know there is many another way to solve ploblem.

ex)
using poll, select(), while(1){ read.... } ....

check event(WaitingOnRead, WaitCommEvent(), SetCommMask Function .. etc..)

but.
they all use thread or synchronous way.

i want 
1. don't use thread
2. Asynchronous way

like

device(RS232C)---->COM  // data receive event occur!!

-> callback func call   // user func like save or printf receive data)

-> run user func

possible?
plz help me...

ps. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx

i don't need .NET Framework solution.

need WIN32 MFC way...

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: you mean title of question is wrong? sorry. I'll be careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

It has been  awhile since this question was posted, so you may have already reached a solution. However if, as i understand your question, you want to read from a serial port asynchronously (ie non blocking) then you have to use threads.
One thread to read the data from the Serial Port, when it arrives, flag that 'Data Available', either by executing a pre-defined piece of code, or preferably by firing a 'Data Available' event. This thread then sleeps until another piece of data arrives.

A second thread then consumes the data, to do whatever you need, but without separate threads you are, by definition, working synchronously.

Answer (score -1):

Using libev you can setpu callbacks to be triggered when data is available on the serial port. Reading and uderstanding of the usage of libev can help.
https://linux.die.net/man/3/ev

Comment: This question is about MFC, a framework for Windows. Proposing to use a library for Linux isn't very helpful.